# Odd Fabric.js Behavior with Image Filter and Cropping

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, fabricjs

I have an odd scenario here. I have a basic fabric.js image object, created from `fabric.Image.fromURL`, and I placed it on the canvas and added an [image filter](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.fabric.Image.filter.BlendColor.html).

Oddly enough, whenever I add an image filter, the image actually *crops*. It seems so unexpected and I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Here's it happening: https://v.usetapes.com/gkWX8CfeUh

---

The logic for adding the filter when mousing over:

```
img.on('mouseover', () => {
  const filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
    color: 'white',
    alpha: 0.2,
    mode: 'tint'
  })
  img.filters.push(filter)
  img.applyFilters()
  this.canvas.renderAll()
})
```

---

**Update**
I've added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0nux8vz/1/) to better show the issue I'm having.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/4Ls7m6qu/)?

Comment: @Durga have just added it in the question

Comment: make `fabric.textureSize = 4096`, and it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/1esckL5x/)